# change event not getting fired in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Hi i am calling method onchange event but for calender input it is not getting applied.Below is the code.[(change)="makeDirty()"].It is working for description textbox but not working for date picker textbox.

```
    <div class="form-group mb-10">
      <label class="formLabel">Description</label>
      <input type="text" (change)="makeDirty()" class="form-control bg-grey" [(ngModel)]='description' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-10">
        <label class="formLabel">Period</label>
        <input type="text" (change)="makeDirty()" placeholder="select start date and end date" class="form-control bg-grey" #dp="bsDaterangepicker"
          bsDaterangepicker [(ngModel)]="bsRangeValue" [placement]="'top'" [outsideClick]="false" [bsConfig]="{  showWeekNumbers:false,containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue',rangeInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }"
          formControlName="Period">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar glyicon" (click)="dp.toggle()" [attr.aria-expanded]="dp.isOpen"
          value="Toggle" style="top:36px"></span>
        <div class="alert  alert-danger" *ngIf="formGroup.get('Period').dirty && formGroup.get('Period').errors && formGroup.get('Period').errors.ageRange ">
          Date range selected is invalid
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please help me I am new to angular.

Answer (score 5):

Use `(bsValueChange)` for datepicker. See documents

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#value-change-event

Comment: before doing any changes it is calling the makeDirty() method on page load

Comment: @user9287106 Does `makeDirty()` function get called when you click on the calendar for the first time?

Comment: No,on page load it is getting called but i want it on change

Comment: @user9287106 can try `onShown()` function instead of `change` function?

Answer (score 1):

Use (input) instead of (change).

Comment: I tried but not working not calling the method even after change

Comment: Any errors on developer console? I dont see closing tag of your input element in above piece. Also, your are using ngmodel and formcontrolname together?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ngModel, you can use (ngModelChange).

Comment: Yes i am using ngModel,when I use ngModelChange it is calling makeDirty() method on load before making any changes.

Comment: You can use something like this   makeDirty() { 
   if (bsRangeValue){ console.log('Called');}
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try **ES6 setter**

> The set syntax binds an object property to a function to be called
>   when there is an attempt to set that property.

Inside setter function place makeDirty method it will be called whenever the input value change

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  set myDateValue(value) {
    this.makeDirty();
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    // this.myDateValue = new Date();
  }

  onDateChange(newDate: Date) {
    console.log(newDate);
  }

  makeDirty() {
    console.log('Called');
  }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-uyskw9